# How to create pyspark dataframe from a dict with tuple as value?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark

How to create pyspark dataframe from a dict with tuple as value?

```
[['HNN', (0.5083874458874459, 56)], ['KGB', (0.7378654301578141, 35)], ['KHB', (0.6676891615541922, 18)]]
```

The output should looks sth like that (please see attached ss)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to merge the string and tuple within each list.

This can be accomplished with list comrehension where you take element 0 (the string) and unpack element 1 (the tuple) using `*` into a list for each list in your list of lists.

```
l= [['HNN', (0.5083874458874459, 56)], ['KGB', (0.7378654301578141, 35)], ['KHB', (0.6676891615541922, 18)]]

df = spark.createDataFrame([[x[0],*x[1]] for x in l], ['col_1','col_2','col_3'])
```

Output

```
+-----+------------------+-----+
|col_1|             col_2|col_3|
+-----+------------------+-----+
|  HNN|0.5083874458874459|   56|
|  KGB|0.7378654301578141|   35|
|  KHB|0.6676891615541922|   18|
+-----+------------------+-----+
```